# Unable to log in to one specific user account in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: boot, 10.04

Suddenly I am unable to log in into one of my user (user1) accounts, it is blinking after booting although for other user accounts I am able to log-in properly. My /home/user1 directory is 70% full. I am able to log-in through terminal to the user account user1. How to solve this problem ? URGENT

Comment: What did you do that might have caused this error? Did you change keyboards, or keyboard lay-out? What was the last time you succesfully logged in with this user?

Comment: today only, I have not done anything other than restarting after which this problem has started

Answer (score 0):

If it logs in to another account, then turn off 'Automatic Login.' This should take you to the Login Screen every time.

To do it, go to: System Settings -> User Accounts. Click on the user that is logged in at boot and turn off the automatic login feature. **Note:** It may ask for a Admin password if you are on a 'Standard User' account.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to access user1 account through GUI. How turning off "Automatic Login" will help ? In the list of user accounts "user1" is not shown. I tried to log-in through "other" providing username as "user1" and password of user1, but same problem